# Does all Mac have a scalar (per channel) volume support?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I develop an application that rely on the sound output of Mac.

The Mac Mini and the Mac Pro have only one speaker. Does they just have a master volume or does they have also a scalar volume with only one channel ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you provide full stereo sound with independent volume channels and it will be converted to mono for the single speaker. Look up Core Audio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't use Core Audio. I'm using the AudioHardware low-level functions which correspond to the needs of my application.

Comment: You are using Core Audio. AudioHardware is part of Core Audio.